# Viewing segments via the MailChimp export api

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm having trouble using the API to view a segment. I'm using PHP. My code is as follows:

```
$url = "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list/?apikey=$api_key&id=$list_id&$segment"; 
$result = file_get_contents($url);
```

where `$segment` is an array used to generate the segment.

I can get the following version working...

```
$segment = "segment[match]=all"
           "&segment[conditions][0][field]=LNAME".
           "&segment[conditions][0][op]=like".           
           "&segment[conditions][0][value]=smith";
```

which generates a segment of all subscribers to my list with a last name containing "smith".

However, what I actually want to do is generate a segment based on people who've been sent any mailer in the last 7 days. I've created this manually to get the correct fields and generated the following array based on it:

```
$segment = "segment[match]=all".
           "&segment[conditions][0][condition_type]=Aim".
           "&segment[conditions][0][field]=aim".
           "&segment[conditions][0][op]=sent".
           "&segment[conditions][0][value]=last7day";
```

but it's giving me a 300 error. This isn't listed in MailChimp's current error glossary on the export api documentation, but according to a snapshot of the old error documentation means "Campaign doesn't exist" (https://web.archive.org/web/20130209144951/https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/exceptions.field.php) which is weird because I'm not referencing a campaign.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

// , Click on playground and with your API key.

Generate some responses and look at the campaign id.

It's not the integer value you see when hovering over the campaign with `id=`, it's another value.

Look for the `id` that the API needs in the response.

This will fix your issue.